# Converting dtype('int64') to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data with type `dtype('int64')`

```
Portugal    76
Germany     536
Argentina   637
```

What I need is make it pandas dataframe with, I need this is pandas dataframe

```
Country     Count
Portugal    76
Germany     536
Argentina   637
```

Comment: Is it a pandas series .?

Comment: if I type `df.dtype` os `dtype('int64')` , probably it is a series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think input data are Series, so need:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Works as expected